# Не получается на c# .NET 2.0 отправить get запрос, в чем ошибка?

Tags: c#, windows

Система Windows XP SP3 + .NET Framework 2.0 SP2

Ошибка 0xe0434f4d

```
string rs = "";
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://2ip.ru/");
req.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
req.Method = "GET";
req.KeepAlive = true;
req.Headers.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36";
req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8";
req.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
req.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7");
req.Timeout = 10000;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
rs = reader.ReadToEnd();
response.Close();
```

На Windows 7 отлично запускается скомпилированный EXE,
На Windows XP - вылестает с ошибкой этот же EXE файл.

EventType : clr20r3     P1 : test_2.0.exe     P2 : 1.0.0.0     P3 : 8bfd9a43
P4 : system     P5 : 2.0.0.0     P6 : 4889de7a     P7 : 1f6d     P8 : 1bd
P9 : system.net.webexception

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Первая синяя ссылка, что там?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Добавил информацию

Comment: Это все не то... Должна быть информация об ошибке. Делайте тогда логгирование всех необработанных исключений. Сейчас у вас просто информация которая говорит "Упс, ошибка.".

Comment: @EvgeniyZ 0xe0434f4d

Comment: [Exception code: 0xe0434f4d duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37741567/2881286)